# Interface Builder "view - image view" relationship

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm following a tutorial and I need reproduce a situation.

In Interface Builder I want to connect my view (iucontrollerview) with a "Image view" like this picture:

[image]

In my project I have a "view - view" relation like the next picture:

[image]

How I can get a "view - image view" relationship?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode (Interface Builder), on the right panel in the identity inspector you can set the class name of the view IBOutlet. Enter UIImageView. This will change the view class from UIView to UIImageView.